# Adding Bearer Tokens to swagger doesn't work Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, swagger, swagger-ui, bearer-token

I have added the swagger config class as below,

```
@Configuration
@SecurityScheme(
        name = "Bearer Authentication",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
        bearerFormat = "JWT",
        scheme = "bearer"
)

public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI().info(new Info().title("Tutor Student API")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .description("Desc"));
    }
```

And in the controller I have added like this.

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/tutors/")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")
public class tutorController {
  @PostMapping(save")
  public ResponseEntity<TutorResponse> saveTutor(Authentication authentication,
                                                                        @Valid @RequestBody(required = true) Tutor tutor, BindingResult bindingResult) {
```

Here after all these changes  still I can submit a post request without the Bearer token and get 200 Success response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller :

`@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")` has to name the right requirement name :

try :
`@SecurityRequirement(name = "Bearer Authentication")`

Regards

Comment: Even after doing this change I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: did you follow all instruction there ? https://www.baeldung.com/openapi-jwt-authentication

Comment: I did follow the same. But getting this error

Comment: the name should match in `@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")`